# переписать код, используя исключительно async await и try, catch

Tags: javascript, async-await

````
       const getTodosByIds = (ids) => {
           const requests = ids.map((id) => fetch(`${TODOS_URL}/${id}`));
           Promise.all(requests)
               .then((responses) => {
                   const dataResults = responses.map((data) => data.json());
                   return Promise.all(dataResults)
       })
       .then((allTasks) => {
           console.log(allTasks);
       })
       .catch((error) => {
           console.log(error);
       })
}
 
getTodosByIds([43, 21, 55, 100, 10]);```
````